# How to change icon showing my location on google map? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

A blue dot shows my location on google map. 
[a blue dot](https://ibb.co/YNvBNDB)

I want to change this icon. I even want to show it in an animated shape. It would be nice to show it as in this design
[focus center](https://dribbble.com/shots/6651566-Scooter-App-Concept-Motion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package to get current geo-location, and pin your custom marker, currently flutter google map doesn't support gif or any animated image, of course you can also place a animated image using Stack widget on top of map as a fake 'my location' marker.

Remember to disable default current location.